# How create a method who submit a form with parameters

Tags: php, symfony

I have a [page](http://nbp.pl/home.aspx?c=/ascx/archa.ascx)
On this page is the form with two selects year and month. I want to create something like that

```
getTable($year, $month)
{
}
```

After execute this method it get access to specific table. If I'll choose 2013 and kwiecien in method then I get specify page with tables.
I don't know how to send data to form using a code, what have I use? I use Symfony2

Edit:
SOLUTION

```
   $urltopost = "http://nbp.pl/transfer.aspx?c=
   /ascx/listaabch.ascx&Typ=a&p=rok;mies&navid=archa";
            $datatopost = array (
            "mies" => "05",
            "rok" => "12"                
            );

            $ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            // var_dump($returndata);
            print_r($returndata);
```

It's solved my problem,

Comment: php or aspx?, your webpage uses aspx not php...if php, then ill create you an example about it

Answer (score 0):

let me assume that your website is based on PHP language..

let say that your web domain was "www.example.com" and we need to pass using GET process "/home.php?year=2013" or "/home.php?year=2013&month=12"

lets initialized the **home.php** with **year** is equal to **2013** and **month=12** is December

**Inside your php code:**

```
<?php
    function getTable($year,$month)
    {
        //Initializing global var
        $year = 0;
        $month = 0;
        $result = "";
        //check if GET process "year" is set, and must not empty
        if(isset($year) && $year != "")
        {
            //anti sql injection, and passing $_GET process to variables
            $year = mysql_real_escape_string($year);
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE year=$year & month=$month") or die(mysql_error());

            //check if GET process "month" is set as well, and must not empty
            if(isset($month) && $month != "")
            {
                //anti sql injection, and passing $_GET process to variables
                $month = mysql_real_escape_string($month);
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE year=$year") or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }

        //check if $result doesnt have an error,security purposes
        if($result) {
            //loop the datas
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                if($month == 0) {
                    echo $row['year'];
                }else {
                    echo $row['year']." ".$row['month'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    getTable($_GET['year'], $_GET['month']);
?>
```

This is just an example, and it depends on you on how you use it...The Selection statement are just examples and needed to change...without any examples of your needs you must change the **getTable functions** prior to your needs...